# How can iterate over a dataframe using a function with multiple variables from the dataframe?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have function for calculating distance from a location and a dataframe that includes the latitude and longitude of several cities. How can I apply the function to the dataframe and specify which columns to use? I want to specify the longitude and latitude columns in the dataframe and the add another column to the dataframe to store the result.

```
distance <- function(longitude,latitude){
  distm(c(longitude, latitude), c(-121.24, 38.80), fun = distHaversine) * 0.000621371
}

df$distance <- distance(df$long, df$lat)
```

Everything I know to try has passed in the list instead of single value and I'm not sure how to properly iterate over each row. I've looked at function like apply and lapply but I don't know how to use properly specify the columns to use.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To specify dataframe columns as vector inputs for a function with multiple parameters one could use the `mapply` function.

```
df$distance <- mapply(distance, longitude = df$long, latitude = df$lat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dplyr solution, which would also play well with the sf package that handles spatial information smoothly.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
mutate(Distance = distance (long, lat))
```

Would add a "Distance" column using the long and last columns from df. You may have to insert `rowise() %>%` before the mutate call, I'm not doing know if distance is vectorised or not